# How to generate a random vector between two vectors?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I've got two real-valued vectors:

```
vec1 = np.array([a, b, c])
vec2 = np.array([x, y, z])
```

What is a good way to generate a random vector on the line between the two vectors? So the random vector would have elements from the intervals a thru x, b thru y, and c thru z, respectively. Here's what I've got so far, but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

```
vec3 = np.array([np.random.uniform(vec1[i], vec2[i]) for i in range(len(vec1))])
```

Edit: I realized (thanks to the answer below) that this solution only finds a vector that lies in the box generated with the two vectors at opposite corners, rather than finding a vector on the line between the two vectors.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your solution, nor do I think there is a more efficient way to do it. Maybe someone else comes up with something, but I doubt it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random
vec3 = vec1 + random.uniform(0, 1) * (vec2 - vec1)
```

Comment: Whats wrong with my solution. It will give you a random vector on the line between your vectors? Your solution will give a random vector in the 3D space where the two vectors are 2 of the corners.

Comment: Try to edit the question and add a description how does this code solve the question.